# Gui Scale on Linux HD display

Tags: ide, linux, ubuntu, fedora

I use Fedora 24/25 and now Ubuntu 17.04 Gnome on my Lenovo Yoga 900, which has an extremely high pixel density display. For these situations on Mac and Windows, I find a `gui.scaling` option in the Arduino settings. However, on Linux there is no such option, and entering it in `~/.arduino15/settings.txt` does not have any effect.
The version I use is Arduino 1.6.4 (now 2.1.0.5) from the Fedora (Ubuntu) repos. Is the scaling gui option not implemented on linux? Or is there some fix for this?
On the physical display the following screenshot has an approximate width of 4cm -> the green buttons are not usable at all!
[image]

Comment: Maybe related to [this issue](https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/issues/6025).

Comment: Not really, as the user there asks for buttons to customize the UI. I am missing the buttons, which should already be there! Or similarly, I've tried modifying the uiscale via the preferences file, also with no result.